# how to get selected number of rows in SELECT statement?

Tags: php, sql

I want to get the number of rows selected and `sender` value from the table using sql query.

```
$sql='SELECT sender 
      FROM messages 
      WHERE message_id = :message_id';
$sender_result = $db->query($sql, array(':message_id'=>$message_id));
$sender = $sender_result->fetch();
```

Please Help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use count and group by that gives you the number of rows for each sender

```
SELECT sender, COUNT(*) As CNT
FROM messages
WHERE message_id = :message_id
GROUP BY sender
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably need to retrieve the number of rows separately, with a query something like:

```
select count(*) 
    from messages 
    where message_id = :message_id;
```

Comment: yep, it gives the number of rows. but the value of `sender`??

Comment: @MangalaEdirisinghe: Your existing query appears to retrieve `sender`. Is there a problem with what it's doing/how it's working?

Comment: Why running query twice? Not very effective

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$sql='SELECT sender 
      FROM messages 
      WHERE message_id = :message_id';
$sender_result = $db->query($sql, array(':message_id'=>$message_id));
$senders = $sender_result->fetchAll();
$count = count($senders);
```

it will store all result rows in $senders, so you just count this variable. Also you get all senders(dont know if they are the same or different...)